# ConnectionError When Running Python Script

Tags: python, scripting, urllib

The code below has been modified to handle HTTPErrors, but when executing the code, a connection error pops up as so:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
gaierror                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py in _new_conn(self)
    156             conn = connection.create_connection(
--> 157                 (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw
    158             )

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py in create_connection(address, timeout, source_address, socket_options)
     60 
---> 61     for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
     62         af, socktype, proto, canonname, sa = res

~\Anaconda3\lib\socket.py in getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags)
    751     addrlist = []
--> 752     for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
    753         af, socktype, proto, canonname, sa = res

gaierror: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

NewConnectionError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    671                 headers=headers,
--> 672                 chunked=chunked,
    673             )

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in _make_request(self, conn, method, url, timeout, chunked, **httplib_request_kw)
    386         else:
--> 387             conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
    388 

~\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in request(self, method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
   1251         """Send a complete request to the server."""
-> 1252         self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
   1253 

~\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in _send_request(self, method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
   1297             body = _encode(body, 'body')
-> 1298         self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
   1299 

~\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in endheaders(self, message_body, encode_chunked)
   1246             raise CannotSendHeader()
-> 1247         self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
   1248 

~\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in _send_output(self, message_body, encode_chunked)
   1025         del self._buffer[:]
-> 1026         self.send(msg)
   1027 

~\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in send(self, data)
    965             if self.auto_open:
--> 966                 self.connect()
    967             else:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py in connect(self)
    183     def connect(self):
--> 184         conn = self._new_conn()
    185         self._prepare_conn(conn)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py in _new_conn(self)
    168             raise NewConnectionError(
--> 169                 self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e
    170             )

NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000001F9B39F7588>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

MaxRetryError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    448                     retries=self.max_retries,
--> 449                     timeout=timeout
    450                 )

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    719             retries = retries.increment(
--> 720                 method, url, error=e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]
    721             )

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py in increment(self, method, url, response, error, _pool, _stacktrace)
    435         if new_retry.is_exhausted():
--> 436             raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
    437 

MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='jackmaryetc.com', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /Travel/US/Colorado/images/052cat.jpg (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000001F9B39F7588>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ConnectionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-bbe9df161c0c> in <module>
     12             RQs = 0
     13 
---> 14         response = requests.get(row[0])
     15         if response.status_code == 200:
     16             with open(filename, 'wb') as f:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py in get(url, params, **kwargs)
     73 
     74     kwargs.setdefault('allow_redirects', True)
---> 75     return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
     76 
     77 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py in request(method, url, **kwargs)
     58     # cases, and look like a memory leak in others.
     59     with sessions.Session() as session:
---> 60         return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
     61 
     62 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py in request(self, method, url, params, data, headers, cookies, files, auth, timeout, allow_redirects, proxies, hooks, stream, verify, cert, json)
    531         }
    532         send_kwargs.update(settings)
--> 533         resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
    534 
    535         return resp

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py in send(self, request, **kwargs)
    644 
    645         # Send the request
--> 646         r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
    647 
    648         # Total elapsed time of the request (approximately)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    514                 raise SSLError(e, request=request)
    515 
--> 516             raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
    517 
    518         except ClosedPoolError as e:

ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='jackmaryetc.com', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /Travel/US/Colorado/images/052cat.jpg (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000001F9B39F7588>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed'))
```

I tried to fix this by setting a sleep function as I read somewhere that this error might be caused by too many requests being sent out in quick succession. Thee script is supposed to take urls from a csv file, download it and put the image in the correct folder as described in the csv file. Below I have pasted the code:

```
with open('images.csv') as csv_file:
csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
next(csv_reader)
RQs = 0
for row in csv_reader:
    basename = os.path.basename(urlparse(row[0]).path)
    filename = '{}/{}/{}'.format(row[2], row[1], basename)

    if RQs == 200:
        time.sleep(1)
        print("sleeping for 1 second")
        RQs = 0

    response = requests.get(row[0])
    if response.status_code == 200:
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.content)

    RQs += 1
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: first check `print(row[0])` to see if you use correct URL because I see error `gaierror: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed` which can mean problem with URL or network connection (no access to network or to DNS server or wrong URL)

Comment: I have already checked this before and also opened the image to make sure that the image actually exists. The csv file has about 1400 urls and I'm able to download 301 images before this error pops up.

Comment: first use `print()` to see which url makes problem - and test this url in web browser. Error `getaddrinfo failed` can means problem with DNS server and it can't convert URL to IP.

Comment: You were right, but how can I skip over such urls?

Comment: inside `for`-loop use `try/except` to catch error.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to post a working version of the code:

```
with open('images.csv') as csv_file:
csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
next(csv_reader)
RQs = 0
for row in csv_reader:
    basename = os.path.basename(urlparse(row[0]).path)
    filename = '{}/{}/{}'.format(row[2], row[1], basename)

    if RQs == 200:
        time.sleep(1)
        print("sleeping for 1 second")
        RQs = 0

    try:
        response = requests.get(row[0])
        if response.status_code == 200:
            print(row[0])
            with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
                f.write(response.content)
    except ConnectionError as e:
        print(e)
        r = "No response"

    RQs += 1
```